# How do you to find missing numbers in a row

Tags: excel

I have a Row and the range is B2:B10 and the numbers are from 1 - 9. At random about 1/2 of those numbers will be placed in this Row and need the formula to tell me what numbers are missing. Of course, I can simply look and tell what they are but would like for the formula to let me know. When you ask this question on the Internet it gives the solution for Columns and not Rows. I know this involves an array, but haven't quite mastered that yet.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please confirm will the numbers be duplicated in the range, e.g. number 3 appears more than once in the range? In addition, can you please provide an example with the expected outcome?

Comment: There are no duplicates in numbers from 1 - 9

Comment: @jeh Can you try my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`=TEXTJOIN(",",,IF(ISERROR(MATCH({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},B2:B10,0)),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},""))` should work if a you need a list of numbers not included.

Comment: that's what I needed. Thanks, and I like your name.

Comment: Good answer but really inefficient to check many numbers. So, you can use `SEQUENCE()` function to scale it without hardcoding checking numbers.

Comment: @Harun24HR simply replace `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}` with `ROW(1:9)` will eliminate your concern. One can change `9` to `20` to have the same outcome as your solution.

Answer (score 0):

So, for large number it is hard to hardcode numbers in array. You may like this dynamic approach where you do not need to hardcode numbers rather you can just use `SEQUENCE()` function (if your Excel have it) to define how many numbers you want to check. Try-

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(ISERROR(MATCH(SEQUENCE(20),B2:B10,0)),SEQUENCE(20),""))
```

[image]

Comment: @Haurn24HR, thanks I will give that a try also.